# Displaying status and performing download in one main loop

Tags: c, libcurl

I'm writing a small download manager in C with libcurl, and have encountered an interesting problem. It seems that I did not properly understand how `curl_multi_perform` works until now, once I discovered this main loop actually only downloads 16 KiB per handle per second:

```
while (1) {
    int cmp_rem;
    j_recount_speeds();
    j_handle_completed();
    j_handle_waiting();
    curl_multi_perform(j_curlm, &cmp_rem);
    j_status();
    sleep(1);
}
```

I had a look at some [examples on cURL's website](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html) involving the multi interface, and discovered that the right way to do things is to `select` on the socket file descriptor, recalling `curl_multi_perform` once ready.

I want to be able to run `j_recount_speeds`, `j_handle_completed`, `j_handle_waiting` and `j_status` at regular time intervals, though. Can I do this as well as what I need to do with `curl_multi_perform` in one main loop, or do I need to use separate threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need separate threads, you just need to understand what interfaces are available for you. Firstly, you can issue a select() with a timeout:

```
while (continue_condition_true) {
    struct timeval tv = { 1, 0 }; /* 1 second, zero microseconds */

    /* Select returns 0 if it has timed out */
    if (select(nfds, readfds, writefds, exceptfds, &tv) == 0) {
        /* perform timeout operations here */
        continue;
    }
}
```

Please note that this requires real error-checking on the return value from select(); this code is for edutainment only!

Secondly, you can use gettimeofday() to check for elapsed time:

```
struct timeval base_tv, tmp_tv;

gettimeofday(&base_tv, NULL);

/* do your processing here */

gettimeofday(&tmp_tv, NULL);

if (tmp_tv.tv_sec - base_tv.tv_sec > 0) {
    /* perform timeout operations here */

    /* update base_tv to new 'base' time */
    gettimeofday(&base_tv, NULL);
}
```

This is, of course, only a course timeout (and ignores microseconds in the comparison), but for the purposes of updating cURL's display for a user should be more than adequate.

EDIT:

Extracting fdset info from a CURLM struct appears, according to the docs, to go thusly:

```
fd_set readfds, writefds, exceptfds;
struct timeout tv = { 1, 0 }; /* 1-second timeout */
int nfds;

/* extract fd_set data from CURLM data */
curl_multi_fdset(curlm, &readfds, &writefds, &exceptfds, &nfds);
select(nfds, &readfds, &writefds, &exceptfds, &tv);
```

Again, for edutainment only, real error-handling code needs to go in here, warranty void in Narnia, etc.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail how `select` works in the context of `curl_multi_perform`? As I'm very unfamiliar in this area, I'm not really sure how this works and how I should modify my code.

Comment: according to http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_perform.html, you would call curl_multi_fdset(http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_fdset.html) to retrieve the fdsets you would then pass to select(); quick example will be posted above shortly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm quite busy right now and don't have a chance to fiddle with my code yet, so I apologise in advance for taking some time before accepting your answer.

Comment: Thanks again for answering. I'll accept this answer, though I'll probably end up going with threads anyway if the queue processing becomes more expensive and starts locking up the program.

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance. You're probably going to be spending more time waiting for packets than doing processing, to be honest.